# Riverpod is not rebulding expected widget

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying out riverpod. When I tried 'watch' (as I did with provider), the widget is not updating. If I go back and come back to this page, only then it rebuilds and I see changes.

```
final randomize = Provider((_) => RandomizeChangeNotifier());
...
...
Text(
      ref.watch(randomize).randomNumber?.toString() ??
          'Generate A Random Number',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
    )
```

ChangeNotifier class:

```
class RandomizeChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {

  final random = Random();
  
  int? _randomNumber;

  get randomNumber => _randomNumber;

  int min = 0;
  int max = 0;

  generateRandomNumber(){

    _randomNumber = min + random.nextInt(max + 1 - min);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Full repo link: https://github.com/Cyberavater/randomizer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final randomize = Provider((_) => RandomizeChangeNotifier());
```

should be a ChangeNotiferProvider

```
final randomize = ChangeNotifierProvider((_) => RandomizeChangeNotifier());
```